Evaluating the integral $\int -\frac{12x + 13}{2 \sqrt{2x + 1} \left(3x - 2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}} \, dx$
To evaluate the integral
$\int -\frac{12x + 13}{2 \sqrt{2x + 1} \left(3x - 2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}} \, dx$
I Substituted $u = 3x - 2$
Let $u = 3x - 2$, which implies that
$\frac{du}{dx} = 3 \quad \Rightarrow \quad dx = \frac{du}{3}$.
Now I  expressed $x$ in terms of $u$ as:
$x = \frac{u + 2}{3}$.
Substituting $x = \frac{u + 2}{3}$ into $2x + 1$, we get:
$2x + 1 = 2\left(\frac{u + 2}{3}\right) + 1 = \frac{2u + 4 + 3}{3} = \frac{2u + 7}{3}$.
Thus, $\sqrt{2x + 1}$ becomes:
$\sqrt{2x + 1} = \sqrt{\frac{2u + 7}{3}}$.
Now rewriting the integral in terms of $u$:
$\int -\frac{12\left(\frac{u + 2}{3}\right) + 13}{2 \sqrt{\frac{2u + 7}{3}} \, u^{\frac{5}{2}}} \cdot \frac{du}{3}$.
This is getting quite complex can anyone please help me in completing the evaluation of this integral

To differentiate to that integrand, it may be something of the form $F=(2x+1)^a(3x-2)^b$. Differentiating this:
\begin{align}
F'&=2a(2x+1)^{a-1}(3x-2)^b+3b(2x+1)^a(3x-2)^{b-1}\\
 &= (2x+1)^{a-1}(3x-1)^{b-1}[2a(3x-2)+ 3b(2x+1)] &\text{ so $a=\frac12$, $b=-\frac32$}\\
 &= \frac1{2(2x+1)^{1/2}(3x-1)^{5/2}}[2(3x-2) -9(2x+1)]\\
 &= \frac1{2(2x+1)^{1/2}(3x-1)^{5/2}}(6x-4-18x-9)\\
 &= \frac1{2(2x+1)^{1/2}(3x-1)^{5/2}}(-12x-13)\\
\end{align}
And we see it's set up for this to work, i.e.
$$F=\frac{\sqrt{2x+1}}{(3x-2)^{3/2}}+c$$

Rewriting the integral as
$$
I=\int \sqrt{\frac{3 x-2}{2 x+1}} \cdot \frac{12 x+13}{(3 x-2)^3} d x
$$Let $t=\sqrt{\frac{3 x-2}{2 x+1}}$, then $ x=\frac{t^2+2}{3-2 t^2}$ and $x=\frac{t^2+2}{3-2 t^2}$.
Putting back yields
$$
I=\int \frac{2\left(9-2 t^2\right)}{7 t^4} d t=-\frac{6}{7 t^3}+\frac{4}{7 t} =\frac{2}{7\left(\frac{3 x-2}{2 x+1}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\left(2 \cdot \frac{3 x-2}{2 x+1}-3\right) = -\frac{2 \sqrt{2 x+1}}{(3 x-2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}+C
$$
checked by WA.

Since the “most problematic term” is $(3x-2)^\frac52$, the integration would be easier if we could reduce its power. This can be done by rewriting the numerator as:
$$-6x-\frac{13}2=-2(3x-2)-\frac{21}2$$
$$\implies -\int\frac{12x+13}{2\sqrt{2x+1}(3x-2)^\frac52}\mathrm dx= -2\underbrace{\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{2x+1}(3x-2)^\frac32}}_{\mathcal I_1}-\frac{21}2\underbrace{\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{2x+1}(3x-2)^\frac52}}_{\mathcal I_2}$$
For evaluating $\mathcal I_1$, notice that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(3x-2\right)^{-\frac12}=-\frac12(3x-2)^{-\frac32}$, so it would be feasible to substitute $(3x-2)^{-\frac12}=t\implies 3x-2=\frac1{t^2}$:
$$\mathcal I_1=\frac2{\sqrt{21}}\int\frac{t\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^2+\frac27}}$$
You can take it from here.
Similarly, for evaluating $\mathcal I_2$, substitute $(3x-2)^{-\frac32}=t$:
$$\mathcal I_2=\frac2{3\sqrt3}\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{2t^{-\frac23}+7}}$$
$$=\frac2{3\sqrt{21}}\int\frac{t^\frac13\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{t^\frac23+\frac27}}$$
Now, a sneaky thing to notice is that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}t^\frac23=\frac23 t^{-\frac13}$ and $t^\frac13=t^\frac23\cdot t^{-\frac13}$. So, substituting $u=t^\frac23$ in $\mathcal I_2$,
$$\mathcal I_2=\frac1{\sqrt{21}}\int\frac{u\mathrm du}{\sqrt{u+\frac27}}$$
This integral can now be evaluated easily.


This integral can be brute forced with a few substitutions, however note the different domain changes throughout solution. I have put simplified forms after each substitution to keep this answer readable and clear. But, feel free work through the sub yourself!

$$\int -\frac{12x + 13}{2 \sqrt{2x + 1} \left(3x - 2\right)^{{5}/{2}}}\, dx = \int -\frac{12x + 13}{2 \sqrt{2x + 1} \sqrt{3x - 2}\cdot\left(3x - 2\right)^{2}}\, dx$$
$$=\int -\frac{12x + 13}{2 \sqrt{6(x - 1/12)^2 - 49/24}\cdot\left(3x - 2\right)^{2}}\, dx\,, \quad \color{green}{x > 2/3} \label{eq1}\tag{1}$$
Translate the integral by $x = u + 1/12$:
$$=\int -\frac{32\sqrt{6}\cdot(6u + 7)}{\sqrt{144u^2 - 49}\cdot\left(12u - 7\right)^{2}}\, du$$
Now use $u = \dfrac{7}{12}\sec{t}$ and $du = \dfrac{7}{12}\sec{t}\cdot\tan{t}\, dt$:
$$=\frac{7}{12}\int -\frac{32\sqrt{6}\cdot(14\sec{t} + 7)\sec{t}\cdot\tan{t}}{\sqrt{49\tan^2{t}}\cdot49\left(\sec{t} - 1\right)^{2}}\, dt
\\=\int \frac{7}{12} \cdot -\frac{32\sqrt{6}\cdot7\cdot(2\sec{t} + 1)\sec{t}\cdot\tan{t}}{7|\tan{t}|\cdot49\left(\sec{t} - 1\right)^{2}}\, dt
\\=\int -\frac{4\sqrt{6}\cdot(2\cos{t} + 1)}{21\left(\cos{t} - 1\right)^{2}}\, dt$$
Finally, brute force with Weierstrass; $s = \tan{t/2}\,, \cos{t} = \dfrac{1 - s^2}{1 + s^2}$ and $dt = \dfrac{2}{1 + s^2}ds$:
$$\\=-\frac{4\sqrt{6}}{21}\int \frac{2\left( \dfrac{1 - s^2}{1 + s^2} \right) + \left( \dfrac{1 + s^2}{1 + s^2} \right)}{\left(\left( \dfrac{1 - s^2}{1 + s^2} \right) - \dfrac{1 + s^2}{1 + s^2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{2}{1 + s^2}\, ds
\\=\frac{2\sqrt{6}}{21}\int \frac{s^2 - 3}{s^4}\, ds
\\= -\frac{2\sqrt{6}(s^2 - 1)}{21s^3} + C$$

$s = \tan{t/2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - \cos{t}}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos{t}}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - \cos{(\sec^{-1}{7/12u})}}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos{(\sec^{-1}{7/12u})}}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{12u - 7}}{\sqrt{12u + 7}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{3x - 2}}{\sqrt{2x + 1}}$

$$-\frac{2\sqrt{6}\left(\dfrac{2(3x - 2)}{3(2x + 1)} - \dfrac{3(2x + 1)}{3(2x + 1)}\right)}{21\left( \dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{3x - 2}}{\sqrt{2x + 1}} \right)^3} + C
\\=\frac{\sqrt{2x + 1}}{(3x - 2)^{3/2}} + C$$

Substitute $x=\frac{3x-2}{2x+1}$, or $t=\frac{t+2}{3-2t}$
$$\int -\frac{12x + 13}{2 \sqrt{2x + 1} \left(3x - 2\right)^{{5}/{2}}} \, dx=\frac1{14}\int \frac{2t-9}{t^{5/2}}dt=\frac17\left(\frac3{t^{3/2}}-\frac2{t^{1/2}} \right)
$$

How did you come up with the idea to do this substitution?
